# SQL Server not connecting

Tags: sql-server

I have created a form and connected to a SQL Server database. The data entered in the form enters into the database. But when I upload the same form into the upload the form gets submitted the but get an error saying. Please help me out

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 23:
>   Line 24:         SqlConnection con = new
>   SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial
>   Catalog=Accomdation;Integrated Security=True");
>
> Line 25:         con.Open();

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check if server and client setting in "SQL Server Configuration Manager"?  Server side and client side both should both have the same "Protocol" (TCP/IP, Shared Memory, Named Pipe, VIA) enabled.  You can actually specify which one to use in the connection string also.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx